# STM32 SPI Receive interrupt does not trigger

Tags: interrupt, stm32, spi

I want to communicate 2 STM32 boards using SPI. I use one board as master and the other one as slave.

I can transmit and receive using HAL_SPI_Transmit() and HAL_SPI_Receive() functions. Now I want to configure slave to receive in interrupt mode but this interrupt never triggers.

Here is the code I use for both boards:

Master

```
int main(void)
{
  uint8_t txdata [] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04};

  HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();

  MX_SPI2_Init();

  while (1)
  {
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi2, txdata, 4, 20);
    HAL_Delay(2000);
  }
}
static void MX_SPI2_Init(void)
{
  hspi2.Instance = SPI2;
  hspi2.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi2.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi2.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi2.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi2.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi2.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi2.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
  hspi2.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi2.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi2.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi2.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

void HAL_SPI_MspInit(SPI_HandleTypeDef* hspi)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  if(hspi->Instance==SPI2)
  {
    __HAL_RCC_SPI2_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_15|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_13;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF0_SPI2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
  }
}
```

Slave

```
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();

  MX_SPI2_Init();

  HAL_SPI_Receive_IT(&hspi2, rxdata, 4);

  while (1)
  {

  }
}
void HAL_SPI_RxCpltCallback(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi)
{
  if (hspi->Instance == SPI2) 
  {
    printf("%d", rxdata[0]);
    printf("%d", rxdata[1]);
    printf("%d", rxdata[2]);
    printf("%d", rxdata[3]);
    printf("\r\n");

    rxdata[0] = 0;
    rxdata[1] = 0;
    rxdata[2] = 0;
    rxdata[3] = 0;

    HAL_SPI_Receive_IT(&hspi2, rxdata, 4);
  }
}

void HAL_SPI_MspInit(SPI_HandleTypeDef* hspi)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  if(hspi->Instance==SPI2)
  {
    __HAL_RCC_SPI2_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_15|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_13;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF0_SPI2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SPI2_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(SPI2_IRQn);
  }
}

void SPI2_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_SPI_IRQHandler(&hspi2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that BaudPreescaler was set as SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2 in both master and slave but for some reason this variable had different values in each project.

This made communication not work properly and receive noise.